# FullCalendar not displaying right time when using dow: [ int ]

Tags: javascript, date, time, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar to display some events from a DB.
My problem is that when it comes to use dow: [ ], the event starts at 12am, no matter which our I set previously.

Here is my code an a screenshot so you can understand properly what I mean :

```
events: [{
        title: 'Entraînement',
        start: '2017-06-10T21:00:00',
        start: '2017-06-11T21:00:00',
        description: 'Entraînement du Jeudi',
        equipe: 'lol',
        lieu: 'toulouse',
        dow: [ 1 ]
    }

],

eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.find('.fc-title').after("<br/>" + "Desc : " + event.description);
        element.find('.fc-title').after("<br/>" + "Lieu : " + event.lieu);
        element.find('.fc-title').after("<br/>" + "Equipe : " + event.equipe);

    }
```

And here is the screenshot :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xXwr.png

Thanks a lot!

Comment: your event has two "start" properties and no "end" property.

Comment: Yup, I fixed that already. That's not the source of the problem. I found a way to fix my problem anyway.

Comment: @Nofix and the solution was ?